# Cosa sono i "lanci" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

In *Una questione privata*, romanzo di  Beppe Fenoglio ambientato durante la guerra partigiana, ho letto questo dialogo:

> – Vado da Hombre, – rispose Milton.
>         – Vai dai rossi?
>         – Visto che noi azzurri non abbiamo prigionieri.
>         – Ma quelli, ammesso che l’abbiano, non te lo daranno mai.
>         – Me lo farò... imprestare. 
>         – Non te lo presteranno nemmeno. Con la ruggine che c’è, con la testa che gli montano i commissari, con la bile che hanno in corpo per via dei **lanci** che noi riceviamo e loro no...

La mia domanda è sul significato di questi "lanci" che appaiono in questo passaggio. Immagino si tratti di qualche tipo di armamento. Ho cercato alla voce "lancio" di alcuni dizionari, ma il senso non mi è del tutto chiaro. Si tratta di esplosivi (accezione 1. d del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lancio))?

Comment: Mi viene da pansare a "lanci" col paracadute, ossia come se  loro ricevessero (cibo, armi etc.) tramite lanci di paracaduti...just a wild guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I lanci sono sicuramente i "lanci di rifornimenti" (quindi sia armi che munizioni che cibo) che una parte riceve e l'altra no (e quindi è scontenta).

I rifornimenti venivano paracadutati per via aerea, da qui il termine "lancio" (perché venivano lanciati da aerei).

[image]